# How to run a cgi file locally?

Tags: ruby, cgi, localhost

I am new to server-side programming.

A tutorial I am working through has two files: 'index.html' and 'auto.cgi'

I know how to run files from a local server (via python's built-in server or ruby's webrick) which is what I am doing.

However, when I make an ajax request for the 'cgi' file, I get the following error

```
500 (Internal Server Error)
```

Why is this so **?**

---

*Additional information*

The ajax call looks like this (simplified):

```
ajax({
   type: "GET", 
   url: "auto.cgi?to=" + "jason",
   onSuccess: function(html){
       //do stuff
   }
});
```

and the 'auto.cgi' file is as follows:

```
#!/usr/bin/ruby

require 'cgi'

# Get the 'q' parameter out of the incoming Query String
cgi = CGI.new
q = cgi.params['to']

# Our limited 'database' contains a few users
# with their username and full name
data = [
    {
        "user" => "bradley",
        "name" => "Bradley S"
    },
    {
        "user" => "jason",
        "name" => "Jason S"
    },
    {
        "user" => "john",
        "name" => "John R"
    },
    {
        "user" => "josh",
        "name" => "Josh K"
    },
    {
        "user" => "julia",
        "name" => "Julia W"
    }
]

# Make sure that we print out the correct HTML header
print "Content-type: text/html\n\n";

# Now we "search" through the data
for row in data
    # Looking for users that match our auto-complete search
    if(row["user"] =~ /#{q[0]}/i || row["name"] =~ /#{q[0]}/i)

        print '<li id="' + row["user"] + '">
            <img src="icons/' + row["user"] + '_icon.jpg"/>
            <div>
                <span id="username">' + row["user"] + '</span>
                <span id="fullname">' + row["name"] + '</span>
            </div>
        </li>'
    end    
end
```

Comment: Although I don't think your script will work as intended (due to how you match the rows to Strings when you probably want Regexps), I cannot see an obvious error that would cause a 500. Your local server should have either a console output or error log file or both - you should take a look to see if an error message has been sent there along with the 500 that goes to the client (it is normal web server behaviour to log the error details in this way)

Comment: @NeilSlater Thanks for the regex catch! (updated it accordingly)

Comment: I got the 500 error message from the console...

Comment: Not sure if this is relevant, but if I change the request to be one for a plain text file ex. 'auto.txt', the request works as expected with no errors. But as soon as the extension is **'cgi'** I get the 500 error (...even without passing parameters with the cgi call)

Comment: That is possibly server config, and not related to contents of the script. Could you include which server you are testing with, how you start it, and how it is configured.

Comment: @NeilSlater Thanks for the help! I tried running a different local server (this time using python's simple http server) and it worked =). But with a catch, rather than executing the cgi script (with the passed parameters) it just returned the full text content of the cgi script... (I have tested the cgi script in the command line and it works with no problems)

Comment: I have ruby installed on my computer (which is the server in this case? ) if that matters...

Comment: @NeilSlater So, I looked into the server config a bit more, and come across this one in the official docs: `python -m http.server --cgi 8000`
Thanks for pointing me in the right direction!!
I still have other errors but not related ( I think ).